# Export to MediaWiki (.txt)

Tags: windows-7, mediawiki, openoffice

How do I export to MediaWiki (.txt) format from OpenOffice 3 Writer (under Windows 7) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this OpenOffice extension: http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/node/2526